# iOS How do I get the the annotation selected index?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, annotations, mapkit

I load 20 different annotations on a map. When pin is touched I want to grab headline data like so.

```
   PinModel *pinModel = [self.array objectAtIndex:0];
   NSLog(@"pin model %@",pinModel.headline);
```

This grabs the first one out of the list, but I want to grab the headline based on the pin that I selected. I put the method in the didselect annotation method. Is there a way I can tell which pin was selected and grab headline based on that? Any tips or suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: definitely a duplicate, but the answers on that question kind of suck.

Comment: Agree, but a duplicate nonetheless.  Simply following the guidelines of the site.  Don't shoot the messenger. ;)

Comment: @PatrickGoley, I agree with you.  That other question's answers don't directly address this question's requirement.  However, this question is a duplicate of others.

Comment: @user3120225, Is PinModel your annotation class?  Are those the objects you're adding to the map?  If so, you just need to cast view.annotation as PinModel and you'll be able to see your custom properties.  If PinModel is not what you're adding to the map, then the answer posted is the correct approach.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is to implement your own class that conforms to the MKAnnotation protocol. Add a public PinModel property to this class, so your annotation can hold onto it's model directly. In your map view, use this new class to create your annotations and save the PinModel to the property on your custom annotation object. Then, in `didSelectAnnotation:` cast the annotation back to your custom annotation class (for safety, check the class of the annotation before you cast), and get the PinModel directly from the property on the annotation.